# Timing command execution from .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

I'm trying to create my own minimal BASH shell prompt that times execution of each command entered. So far I have a functional prompt that looks appealing for my desires; I'm just missing the time output, like [starship](https://github.com/starship/starship) does. I've tried reading user input from $@, $*, /dev/stdin while using `time` without success. I also tried using `date` at the start of the script and end while subtracting the difference to a similar affect. No matter what I've tried the execution timing is always off or doesn't work at all. I've checked documentation and several sites for suggestions but none worked

The closest result I got was using this snippet below

```
function timer_start {
  timer=${timer:-$SECONDS}
}

function timer_stop {
  timer_show=$(($SECONDS - $timer))
  unset timer
}

trap 'timer_start' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND=timer_stop

PS1="$ ${timer_show}s "
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/604244/209955 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698128/209955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With suggestions from @[KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) - I was able to get a functioning timer working from .bashrc! Currently it gets idle/typing + command execution time (which I think I prefer anyway)

```
prmpt() {
    timeStart=$(date +%s)

    sec=$(((timeStart-timeEnd)%60))
    min=$(((timeStart-timeEnd)%3600/60))
    hr=$(((timeStart-timeEnd)/3600))
    
    timeEnd=$timeStart

    printf '%sh:%sm:%ss' "$hr" "$min" "$sec"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prmpt
timeEnd=$(date +%s)
```